# Top spun up with string under tension problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Homework about spinning top](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/homework-about-spinning-top)

I have a top with an unknown mass. It has a moment of inertia of 4.00 * 10^-7 kgm^2
a string is wrapped around the top and pulls it so that its tension is kept at 5.57 N for a distance of .8 m.

Could somebody help me derive some equations to help with this? Or to get me in the right direction?
I have been trying to derive some sort of equations from KEr = 1/2 * I * w^2 but I cant get anywhere without ending up at radius = radius or mass = mass.

Comment: please give a better title

Comment: This is identical to: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/homework-about-spinning-top

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The work done on the top is force times distance.  So given the MOI you can find $\omega$.